# how to repeat failed transaction - pay button, request payment etc

Tags: payment, payment-gateway, backorder, transactional-mail

are there any options to repeat failed transaction (user didn't complete payment, something interrupted, client accidentally closed browser).
In Magento I cannot see related option - any button Pay Now,
or email trigerred to customer with request to pay again.

I see only Reorder again, but this is not the same.
The same option would be important if admin creates backorder - and what then ?
How to request user to pay for backorder - via Paypal or other payment gateways

Do you know any options for it ? Any payment gate for Europe merchants that supports
this case ?

Thanks
Tomek
http://www.shopmages.com